# Parameter validation failed: parameter value for parameter name <some parameter> does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Any suggestions why this AWS CloudFormation keeps rolling back?

```
{
    "Description" : "Single Instance",

    "Resources" : {
        "EC2Instance" : {
            "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
            "Properties" : {
                "ImageId" : "ami-b73b63a0",
                "InstanceType" : "t2.micro",
                "KeyName" : "aws-key-here",
                "Tags" : [
                    {
                        "Key" : "Name",
                        "Value" : "test"
                    }
                  ],
                "SubnetId" : { 
                    "Fn::Select" : [ "0", { "Ref" : "Subnets" } ] 
                }
            }
        }
    },

    "Parameters": {
        "Subnets": {
            "Type": "List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>",
            "Description": "The list of SubnetIds, for at least two Availability Zones in the region in your Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)"
        }
    }
}
```

The specific error seems to be about the Subnets Ref:

```
    Parameter validation failed: parameter value for parameter name Subnets does not exist. Rollback requested by user.
```

I have already created 1 valid Subnet in my AWS Management Console and tested that it works when spinning up an EC2 Instance manually.

Or is there a way of debugging this / getting more detailed output?

Comment: When you go to execute, is your list of subnet selections showing up fine?

Comment: No. Just that error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Subnets` [Parameter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html) in your template has a type `List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>`, which requires a reference to a list of valid Subnet IDs. The error you are seeing means that you passed at least one invalid Subnet ID to the `Subnet` parameter.

If you're deploying your stack from the AWS CLI using [`aws cloudformation create-stack`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/create-stack.html), you need to pass a valid parameter value using the `--parameters ParameterKey=Subnets,ParameterValue=subnet-12345678` option.

If you're deploying from the Management Console, you need to [specify stack  parameters](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-console-create-stack-parameters.html) using the provided dialog, and select a Subnet ID from the drop-down list.

Comment: So, if you're deploying from the Management Console, isn't there a way of working out which Subnet IDs are available via the CloudFormation template? (i.e. without specifying a Subnet ID in the drop-down list)

Comment: The drop-down list displayed in the Management Console for the parameter should only contain available Subnet IDs, so as long as you select one of those you should be fine. Outside of this, another (less convenient) way to retrieve a list which Subnet IDs are available from the user's account would be to call `aws ec2 describe-subnets --query Subnets[].SubnetId --output text` from the AWS CLI, or the equivalent in any other AWS SDK.

Comment: Yes that did the job. Thanks.

Comment: @wjordan can you please edit this answer to show how to pass multiple elements to a list parameter? `--parameters ParameterKey=Subnets,ParameterValue=subnet-12345678` -> how do I pass multiple subnets?

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem. In my case I created the Key with name "mykey" in Mumbai Region. But when I actually started creating a Cloud Formation Infrastructure I changed the region to US-East. Now in my Cloud Formation Infrastructure I provided the name of Key as "mykey". Now the problem is the key "mykey" was created in Mumbai Region. 
Hence I create the Key once again in "US-East" region and my problem vanished.

Regards
Hitesh

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a problem on credentials key and access key. My default values were another accounts one and I was trying to create a stack on a wrong account.